# PHP: Efficient date string formatting

Tags: php, laravel, performance, datetime, iso8601

Formatting very large numbers of date strings from one format into another is slow.

Within a loop we perform a large number of operations and one of them is changing the format of a date string from `ISO8601` to `Y-m-d HH:MM:SS`. Its costing approx. double the time of the other operations. As there are a large amount of items it adds to a large amount of time.

**Question:** is there a more efficient method to format date strings then:

`$formatted = (new DateTime($IsoString))->format('Y-m-d HH:MM:SS');`

??

Comment: what try format desired format in sql query and work with string instead of DateTime object and create instance DateTime object outside of loop if is necessary

Answer (score 0):

Might be worthwhile benchmarking builtin functions against creating a new class each time:

```
date('Y-m-d HH:MM:SS', strtotime($IsoString));
```

Comment: Although this is builtin. DateTime is a built in php class. `strtotime` had a higher cost then DateTime class